# Owl Carousel autoplay and pagination problems

Tags: jquery, sass, owl-carousel

Carousel in question: https://codepen.io/ben456789/pen/jxVrXJ

I'm building this fairly custom autoplaying & looping Owl Carousel and I've run into some issues, which I've not found a solution for here.

When the carousel `loops` back around to 'tab 1' the `active` class is placed on the correct `div` but the inline styling to position the slide does not update so the slide is shown off screen. Is there something wrong with my options set on the initialisation? I believe I have the same problem when I click on the tabs to go to a specific `slide`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I've stripped out alot of HTML, SCSS and Script which I thought would just cause unnecessary bloat for the purpose of this question. So if there's anything there that your like 'Why's that there??!?!' Just assume is part of something else, i.e video, slide transition animation etc...

And also just for ease if you want to increase the time before the carousel progresses. Line 67 of the js increase that from 10 to whatever you like!

I've tried updating versions of jQuery and Owl Carousel, but this led to no, fix.

jquery version: 1.9.1
Owl Version: 2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found alot of issues have come up with the animationOut & In options with wol carousel in my case, so I changed it out with an alternate and it has fixed my issue! Thank you to the 5 other people who at least saw this question but unfortunately couldn't provide any assistance, your good intentions are clear.